# In soccer commentary, what do Chinese say when a player scores a Goal?

Tags: translation, usage

In English and in Spanish they say "Gooaaaaaalllll" after a player scores. How do the Chinese say goal? (My poor guess: méééééén ?)

Comment: You mean that, in South America, they shout "Goooooooolllllllllllllllllllllll!" for as long as they can when somebody scores. "Gol" is Spanish and Portuguese for "goal". This doesn't happen at all in European commentary as far as I'm aware (and definitely not in British commentary).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Cantonese they say "入波!!!!" (Rù bō)

EDIT: In Mandarian they might say "进球啦" (Jìn qiú La)

Answer (score 6):

In Mandarin, most time it will be  “球进啦” or "进球啦”.

The part of culture seems don't like too much energy commentary. A famous and interesting case was about [The World Cup Commentary 2006 Incident of Huang Jianxiang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huang_Jianxiang#The_World_Cup_Commentary_2006_Incident).

Comment: The case you are showing is because the guy was too excited and said something kinda emotional to the losing team. It is not professional to do that since he did it in the national channel. It is not the culture don't like too much energy commentary, people like that guy and he is still doing good.

Comment: @user1596808, yes, that's why I said "part of culture". From the wiki page also reads "Huang's outburst caused an uproar and then sparked a huge debate online and offline in China". 

I personally like Huang, and think sports should be exciting. But I also disagree when he was being rude to team of Australia.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the former Chinese state televison commentator 刘建宏(https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%98%E5%BB%BA%E5%AE%8F) created a way to say "Gooaaaaaalllll" - "进啦进啦进啦进啦进啦进啦进啦进啦", which makes me mute the tv.

Answer (score 1):

Cantonese: we say 入咗 (yup tso) or 入咗喇 (yup tso lar).

Answer (score 1):

Normal Version: 球进啦！  /  进啦 ！

Liu Jianhong version： 进啦！进啦！进啦！进啦！进啦！进啦！进啦！

Duan Xuan version: 啊！！球进啦！！球进啦~~~~~！！！！！！

Zhan Jun version:贼球进啦！